# SI derived units: Another name for the Volt

Tags: voltage, math, physics, units

\$ V = \frac{Kg \cdot m^2}{s^2A} \$

I know it's basic but I was having a hard time understanding the relationship between volts, ohms, watts, amps and ohms until I broke everything down into base units. The exercise got me thinking about alternate names for the volt. For example, a joule can also be called a newton-meter or a coulomb-volt.

The powers in SI-derived units indicate relationships based on rates of change. For example:

- \$ m \$ - distance
- \$ m/s \$- velocity, change in distance per second
- \$m/s^2 \$ - acceleration, change in velocity per second

Consider:

\$ Kg \cdot m^2  \$ which measures moments of inertia.

That makes volts the acceleration in moments of inertia per amp. That isn't the most helpful observation considering there isn't anything rotating.

Maybe consider:

\$\frac{Kg}{s^2A} \$ which measures Teslas of magnetic strength.

That makes volts... *Teslas of area*?

Are there any helpful unit-based alternate names for the volt?

Comment: Just a note: SI units named after a person are lower case when spelled out and capitalised when abbreviated. V = volt, A = ampere, T = tesla, K = kelvin. You have used Kg = kelvin-grams in your question.

Answer (score 3):

a Volt is a Joule per Coulomb.  so each Coulomb of charge has V Joules of energy packed in them somehow.

an Ampere is a Coulomb per second.  so in one second, I coulombs of charge pass by.

so if I coulombs of charge pass by a boundary, each packing V Joules of energy, that means VI joules of energy are being transferred (or used) each second.  that is the rate of energy usage or *"power"*.

so a Watt is one Joule per Second.  if VI joules of energy are transferred each second, that's a power of VI watts.

an Ohm is a Volt per Ampere.  for each ampere of current stuffed into R ohms of resistance, will result in R volts.  so for I amperes of current stuffed into R ohms, the resulting voltage across the resistances will be IR volts.

Answer (score 2):

Wikipedia's definition of the [volt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Volt#Definition) differs from yours.

$$ V = \frac{\text{potential energy}}{\text{charge}} = \frac{\text{N} \cdot \text{m}}{\text{coulomb}} = \frac{\text{kg} \cdot \text{m} \cdot \text{m}}{\text{s}^2 \cdot \text{A} \cdot \text{s}} = \frac{\text{kg} \cdot \text{m}^2}{\text{A} \cdot \text{s}^3} $$

Note the \$s^3\$.

Otherwise I can't help.

Answer (score 0):

Different names for any unit can be useful, depending on what discipline you are active in, what aspects of the system you want to highlight.

For instance, when designing transformers, the saturation flux of a given core is often rated in volt.seconds, which flips around to computing the output voltage per turn as v = d(total_flux)/dt.

In the battery bank for a car, volts could be considered as the energy per ampere.hour of battery (to within a scale factor of 3600!)

Hydrologists, when considering water supply and flooding capacity, would often quote reservoir capacities in acre.feet, so 1 foot of rain on 10 acres of ground ... you get the drift.